What does "do someone's bidding on" mean?
https://thehill.com/hilltv/rising/4655205-rising-may-10-2024/ says

Speaker Johnson does Trump’s bidding on illegal voting.

What does "bid" mean here?
What does "do someone's bidding on" mean?
"bid" is often used with "for". I guess "on" here can't be replaced with "for", correct? How about "against"?

Bid means 'order, command'.  It's not the same as 'making a bid for' something (offering a sum of money in an auction, or trying to do something)/.

Just to be clear, a person can let it be known that they want something to happen or be done. The "bidding" (ordering) does not have to be a direct command.

To 'do someones' bidding' is a formal, and slightly (not very) old-fashioned expression meaning to obey instructions or requests actually given by that person, and it is often used in situations where contempt for, or disapproval of, excessive or shameful obedience is meant.
The following dictionary entry concentrates on that aspect. To do someone's bidding is always to obey their orders or instructions. Whether that obedience is slavish, undignified, shameful, embarrassing, fawning, cowardly, etc, is dependent on opinion and context.

Do somebody's bidding PHRASE
If you say that someone does another person's bidding, you disapprove
of the fact that they do exactly what the other person asks them to
do, even when they do not want to.
[formal, disapproval]
She is very clever at getting people to do her bidding!

Do Someone's Bidding (Collins Dictionary)
Other dictionary entries may ignore the negative meaning, or just hint at it...:

do someone's bidding, to submit to someone's orders; perform services
for someone:
After he was promoted to vice president at the bank, he expected
everyone around him to do his bidding.

Bidding (Dictionary.com)

Not sure, but my instinct is that bidding does not necessarily imply disapproval.

@PeterKirkpatrick - that's why I wrote 'is often used in situations...'. I shall edit my answer to make it clearer that the expression is ofte, but not always, used disapprovingly.

@PeterKirkpatrick - doing someone's bidding is never dignified.

Thanks. Does "on" in "do one's bidding on something" mean "for" or "against"?

If I am your mother and I tell you to drive slower and you obey then you are doing my bidding on driving. Not sure what you mean by 'for or against'.

@MichaelHarvey - interesting. I have re-read your references and see your point. Personally prior to this thread I always thought to do someone's bidding was an entirely neutral expression. What do I know...

@PeterKirkpatrick - my point is that it can be used neutrally, but often is not.
